# execute bundle exec command with sudo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu-12.04, sudo

If I run the below command, it is working correctly in my staging server.

```
/bin/bash -l -c 'cd /path/to/app && sudo bundle exec rails console production lib/myfile.rb'
```

But the same command is not working in production server.

I am getting error:

```
sudo: bundle: command not found
```

but if I run the same command without sudo it is working correctly.

Please help me to understand why this is happening in production server.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using rvm, try:

```
rvm sudo bundle exec rails console production lib/myfile.rb
```

If you are using rbenv, try https://github.com/dcarley/rbenv-sudo:

```
rbenv sudo bundle exec rails console production lib/myfile.rb
```

Comment: rvm, rbenv are not installed in the production server

Comment: @arivarasan this is probably because you don't have a system-wide installation of bundler (you installed it without sudo). Using `sudo gem install bundler` may fix this.

Comment: `rvm sudo make install` results in "Unrecognized command line argument: 'sudo' ( see: 'rvm usage' )"...